# iOS: how to implement client-side authentication?

Tags: ios, authentication, ssl

I'm currently developing and iOS app and was wondering how to go about implementing client-side authentication with SSL certificates stored on the user's device. This additional security measure would be mainly used to further restrict who would be granted permission to communicate with our servers, as well as partially prevent access to our php code.

The user would first have to authenticate with a traditional username and password, then would present it's client certificate to the server who would simply verify it's legitimacy as well as it's appearance in it's list of known certificates.

I'd like to know how exactly to implement a system like this and iOS, and how efficient it would be.